# TypeScript: Typing a tuple in a callback function

Tags: typescript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
  "user1": {
    "key1": "val1"
  },
  "user2":{
    "key1": "val"
  }
}
```

I am attempting to put this json object in a Map object, which I can do just fine, however, what is bothering me a lot is not being able to set the type of the tuple.

here is the code in question:

```js
    private users: Map<string, <T>> = new Map<string, <T>>();

        const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
        Object.entries(parsedData).forEach(([key: string, value: <T>]): void => {
          console.log('k', key, ': ', 'v', value);
          this.users.set(key, value as any); // Map object
        });
      });
```

the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) unfortunatly talk about assigning tuples rather than declaring a tuple as a callback argument.

with the typing above I get the error:

> 493: Tuple type '[string, unknown]' of length '2' has no element at index '2’.

also if I do not set the *value* as type `any` then I get the error:

> Argument of type 'unknown' is not a member of type `<T>`

even though I am trying to set it above in the `[key, value]` tuple

thanks guys

Comment: Please consider editing the code so as to constitute a [mcve] as in [ask]. Currently the code is [more than half errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/AQ4BwJwSwNwQwC4FNgFcDOSLoFzALJxjAA8w6C0AdgOYA0pAKgHzPAC8wVSA7gUSQrV6TVgAoAlAG4AsACh5AYwD2VCuDjYkAEwAiiOB2AApAMoB5AHIA6MJsxjtB6fPMAjAFZJFCa0iqUUEjoYnZaes7WAGbKEACicIoAFmJiANoA1kgAnnhCULQM8AA2qEh4JCwAuhJ4MMpQ2hxsAN7yoMAqasrFSNbFyjRiAOQZwwxZ2QzDeOPAwzBzJWUuch0ISVDo1hhY25gIYpNFcKUocOjAcFTZ0sAA9Pf8xMqe3gjyAL6rHSDfUkA).  Presumably you want something like `const cb = ([s, n]: [string, number]) => s.length === n; ` but it's hard to tell.

Comment: that is the minimal reproducable code... it's a typing error not a run time error or a crashing error. it is a typescript error....

Comment: "Reproducible" implies that someone else can take that code and see the issue.  [Here's what you get](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/AQ4BwJwSwNwQwC4FNgFcDOSLoFzALJxjAA8w6C0AdgOYA0pAKgHzPAC8wVSA7gUSQrV6TVgAoAlAG4AsACh5AYwD2VCuDjYkAEwAiiOB2AApAMoB5AHIA6MJsxjtB6fPMAjAFZJFCa0iqUUEjoYnZaes7WAGbKEACicIoAFmJiANoA1kgAnnhCULQM8AA2qEh4JCwAuhJ4MMpQ2hxsAN7yoMAqasrFSNbFyjRiAOQZwwxZ2QzDeOPAwzBzJWUuch0ISVDo1hhY25gIYpNFcKUocOjAcFTZ0sAA9Pf8xMqe3gjyAL6rHSDfUkA) from the TypeScript compiler: all errors.  Is that in a class?  What is `<T>`?  What is `data`?

Comment: The added effort you put into getting clean example code that can be dropped into an IDE and demonstrate your issue will be paid off by increasing the chance that you'll get an answer you find satisfactory.  Again, you can type a tuple in a callback like `([s,n]:[string,number])=>{}` and not like `([s: string, n: number])=>{}`.  If that helps, great.  Otherwise, please consider modifying the code.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for you help @jcalz. I would 100% agree with you about reproducible code and normally provide that. However, with a typing error such as this that _is_ the minimal reproducible code... the code in question 100% works as intended. this is going to come off as rude, but, there is no possible way I could provide more relatable code aside for including my dotfiles. thanks gain for your help I do sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: [no possible way?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGrIN7JgexwLmQGcwpQBzZAXwFgAoAEwgQBs4oUEcQTkJwyEIoQDaJMiHIAaNAF0RsgNz16AelXIAFjgDuyBHBDIAknwAeABxbAEwMCwCeyQyBxg4kZAGtnIBsgA3ZFBkME0UXBYWXQp8en5SYCEAOlwoAFFETQAKbJEvGQDZAEpkAF4APkx9biIcFghk6PJsr2SwHAAZXWgAYTgiCGzSgGpkACJCceQxgNS8dq6eqH7B4dKqYuU6NQ1TRIh-MOAiZAAjAFcwYOvyYAChXz4oKBwoeIEkonmMrNz8wjiCiFQioEqEAI4YD+SrVdTPV5QACE9GQaOQ8K4AFssXBkIAAUkJ+KqAD90eS0SSySTUej4a4+A0sQlkAByABMrIJRJ5AD1kPy0bS0fScIyIMzwGyAMxcnny-GADFJhTUePVGs1Wotujo+gMhqMJlMZoF5jhtctVgbSvDoG8UXRyfDkAB5M4AK2Y1xOyAsOCIRGAZ0cyAufggMFAh25pPom22QA)